# Converting an RDD to a Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to create a data frame from an rdd in spark2.
When I try to convert the rdd to a data frame I get an error stating the following

```
error reading Scala signature of org.apache.spark.sql.package: assertion failed: unsafe symbol Unstable (child of package InterfaceStability) in runtime reflection universe
```

Here is my code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{ SparkSession}
object TestLoad extends App{

  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate
  val sc = spark.sparkContext
  val rdd = sc.parallelize(
    Seq(("1", "someval"), ("2", "someval"))
  )

  val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd)
  df.show()
}
```

Comment: The problem here is not converting RDD to Dataframe.
"error reading Scala signature of org.apache.spark.sql.package"
Your import seems not to work, or at least is the source of the problem (try to run with an empty body to confirm). How are you submitting your job ? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53274376/spark-wordcount-assertion-failed-unsafe-symbol-unstable)

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem about your RDD to DFF code. It seems like a problem about your computer's library configuration.
For this type exercising you can use [databricks community notebook](https://community.cloud.databricks.com).
This will provide you to focus on the Spark's capabilities not the library issues.